# How to convert apostrophe's html number to actual apostrophe symbol in angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular2-template

I have a text like this in Db:

[image]

when above text accessed in angular2application and rendered, it is showing HTML number.

ie. single quote(') is showing as "HTML Number &#039"

Html number reference: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

I need to convert html number in the above text to normal apostrophe symbol like "I've". Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate your query with a code-snippet?

However, I strongly feel that trying below will resolve your issue:

```
'I\'ve angular2 application'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object `escapedCharacters` out of  [HTML Escaped Characters](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) and than use it like this:

```js
// For the example just a few Symbols
let escapedCharacters = {
      '<': '&#60;',
      '>': '&#62;',
      '"': '&#34;',
      '&': '&#38;',
      '\'': '&#39;'
    },
    str = "I've angular 2 application",
    result = str
      .split('')
      .map(char => escapedCharacters[char] || char)
      .join('');
 
console.log(result);
```